# Title attribute for richfaces comboBox

Tags: richfaces

Is there a possibility to set the title attribute for the comboBox component in Richfaces?

```
<rich:comboBox title="this doesn't work!!!" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Although `<rich:comboBox>` does not have title attribute, try correcting spelling of `title` in your code

If you want something like defaultLabel inside the box as suggestion then try below.

```
<rich:comboBox defaultLabel ="this doesn't work!!!" />
```

[Reference](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/comboBox.jsf?tab=usage&cid=51506)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my goal is to make the comboBox ready for accessibility.